# Magento 1.7 - Override Navigation.php

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, navigation

I've what seems like it should be a fairly easy fix... in Magento 1.7 CE, I just want to add title attributes to my primary navigation links. I attempted to duplication Navigation.php, as described here: http://seechrisblog.com/2010/05/28/how-to-add-title-attributes-to-magentos-main-nav/, however this has had no effect.

Can anyone tell me how I can override Navigation.php in this version of Magento?

-thanks!

Comment: Have you tried simply over riding it by moving it to your local ?? /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php

Comment: @brentwpeterson That's actually what the article he linked to said to do… ;)

Comment: @pizaul It would help others answer this if you outlined here *exactly* what you tried doing. Also worth noting though is that the article you linked to is dated 2010… very old. And the drawItem method it speaks of modifying has been deprecated since CE 1.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been saying this a lot lately, but nobody pays attention :).
**Starting with CE 1.7 (and EE 1.12) the top menu is not rendered anymore by `Navigation.php`**. That is only used for rendering `catalog.leftnav` (Browse By Category).
The top menu is an instance of `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`. The method responsable for generating the HTML for the menu is `_getHtml` in the class I mentioned above. You can override that and change this code (somewhere around line 114 in the original class file):

```
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . '><span>'
          . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
```

to

```
$html .= '<a href="' . $child->getUrl() . '" ' . $outermostClassCode . ' title="'.$this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) .'"><span>'
         . $this->escapeHtml($child->getName()) . '</span></a>';
```

Comment: Version matters, eh? It's one of the problems we have over on MagentoCommerce forums. You often don't solve 1.7.x.x problems with 1.2.x.x answers. Too much has changed.